# expected ')' before executarAcao

Tags: arduino-uno

here is the code:

```
#define pinSom 7
#define pinRele1 2
#define pinRele2 3
#define tempoMaximoDeUmaPalma 150 //milisegundos
#define tempoMaximoEntrePalmas 500 //milisegundos

int contaPalmas = 0;
long tempoEspera = 0;
long tempoEsperaEntrePalmas = 0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(pinSom, INPUT);
    pinMode(pinRele1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pinRele2, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {{
  // verifica o estado do sensor de som (ele fica normalmente com
  int sensorSom = digitalRead(pinSom) ;

  //se o sensor detectou palmas
  if (tempoEspera == LOW) {

      //espera um tempo para não detectar a mesma palma mais de uma vez
    tempoEspera = tempoEsperaEntrePalmas = millis();
    contaPalmas++;
  }else if ((millis() - tempoEspera) >= tempoMaximoDeUmaPalma)
     tempoEspera = 0;
  }

    //caso exceda o tempo maximo entre palmas, zera o contador de palmas


    {

    if ( (contaPalmas != 0) && ((millis() - tempoEsperaEntrePalmas)
    (i get the error here) executarAcao();
    contaPalmas = 0;
    TempoEsperaEntrePalmas = millis();

 }
}
void executarAcao()
{
   switch (contaPalmas) {
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(pinRele1, !digitalRead(pinRele1));
      break;
   }
```

Comment: Your brackets are a mess.

Comment: Welcome to [Arduino SE!!](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) , I think you add more brackets on `void loop() {{` line , please check again your code!!!

Comment: on SO such questions are closed as "typo error", because they are not worth an answer. answers are downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing closing brackets in the line above your error.

It compiles now, but I have no idea whether it works as you intend.
Try forcing yourself to always open and close brackets when you begin one, and making sure to indent properly.

Also, Arduino code is case-sensitive.

```
#define pinSom 7
#define pinRele1 2
#define pinRele2 3
#define tempoMaximoDeUmaPalma 150 //milisegundos
#define tempoMaximoEntrePalmas 500 //milisegundos

int contaPalmas = 0;
long tempoEspera = 0;
long tempoEsperaEntrePalmas = 0;

void executarAcao()
{
  switch (contaPalmas) {
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(pinRele1, !digitalRead(pinRele1));
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(pinSom, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinRele1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinRele2, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  // verifica o estado do sensor de som (ele fica normalmente com
  int sensorSom = digitalRead(pinSom);

  //se o sensor detectou palmas
  if (tempoEspera == LOW) {
      //espera um tempo para não detectar a mesma palma mais de uma vez
    tempoEspera = tempoEsperaEntrePalmas = millis();
    contaPalmas++;
  }
  else if ((millis() - tempoEspera) >= tempoMaximoDeUmaPalma) {
     tempoEspera = 0;
  }
    //caso exceda o tempo maximo entre palmas, zera o contador de palmas
  else {
    if ((contaPalmas != 0) && (millis() - tempoEsperaEntrePalmas)) {
      executarAcao();
      contaPalmas = 0;
      tempoEsperaEntrePalmas = millis();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means you did not close a pair of brackets, either `{}` or `()`.  The solution is to check through your code to make sure brackets are always in pairs.